# MySQL impossible suspicious connections

Tags: mysql, server

I have a MySQL Community service binded locally to "bind-address=127.0.0.1", bind that suppose no expose it to the internet.

I can't connect externally. However i'm receiving constantly on the log this kind of errors:

```
[Server] IP address '194.**.16.73' could not be resolved: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server. 

[Server] Host name 'hos*<probabily a malicious site>*nnet.biz' could not be resolved: No such host is known. 
With a lot of addreses supicious (including TOR exit points).
```

I see this thread Suspicious Connections to My Database x.x.x.x Could Not Be Resolved

But didn't respond the main question:

How is possible that kind of requests without internet access?

What does fire this? Ok i understand, server want to nslookup it, but, what are trying from that hosts? It's dangerous?

If someone can bring ligth to my life I will be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: I would ask this question at dba.stackexchange.com. Stackoverflow if for programming questions.

Comment: thanks i will do